# Отправка поля по аякс, без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Где я накосячил? 
Вот поле

```
    <pre>
    <input class="text_gnida" id='text_gnida' placeholder="Моё сообщение..." 
    type="text" name="text_gnida">
    </pre>
```

Вот аякс

```
<script>
var first = document.getElementById("text_gnida");
$("#text_gnida").keyup(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {

$.ajax({
url: "pages/blocks/message/dsa.php?set=<? echo $_GET["set"]; ?>",
type: "POST",
data: first.value,
success: function() {
document.getElementById('text_gnida').value = "";
}
});
}

});

</script>
```

Вот ввод в базу

```
 if(isset($_POST['text_gnida']) && !empty($_POST['text_gnida'])){
 $messages = R::dispense('messages');
 $messages->date = time();
 $messages->u_from = $_COOKIE['id'];
 $messages->u_to = $item;
 $messages->message = $_POST['text_gnida'];
 R::store($messages);}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что вы где-то накосячили?

Comment: нет очистки поля, надо в дату переменную засунуть

Comment: уже сделал, но чёт...не работает

Answer (score 0):

Решил вроде, вдруг надо . А в обработчике ошибочно указал путь к файлу проверки доступа

```
$("#text_gnida").keyup(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  var ssa = document.getElementById('text_gnida').value;
  $.ajax({
  url: "pages/blocks/message/dsa.php?set=<? echo $_GET["set"]; ?>",
  type: "POST",
  data: {'text_gnida' : ssa},
  success: function() {
  document.getElementById('text_gnida').value = "";
  }
  });
  }

 });
```